# Solving the non-homogeneous recurrence relation: $g_{n} = 12g_{n-2}-16g_{n-3}+6\cdot 2^n+25n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

$g_{n} = 12g_{n-2}-16g_{n-3}+6\cdot 2^n+25n$ With initial conditions $g_{0} = 23, g_{1} = 37, g_{2} = 42 $

This is a practice question I'm working on, and I'm running into absurd amounts of calculations with everything I have tried. I would really appreciate some guidance on this question, as I get the feeling there must be an easier way, or short cut to this question somewhere.

I've tried using both generating functions and the usual method of solving non-homogeneous recurrence relations.

The first method with generating functions, I let

$$A(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_{n}z^n$$ be a generating function. Putting in the initial conditions, I get:

$$ A(z) = 23 + 37z + 42z^2 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=3} (12g_{n-2}-16g_{n-3}+6\cdot 2^n+25n)z^n$$

after a bunch of simplifying and expressing the RHS in terms of $A(z)$, I get:

$$A(z) =  23 + 37z + 42z^2 + 12z^2(A(z)-23) - 16z^3A(Z)+ \frac{6}{1-2z}+25(\frac{z}{(1-z)^2} - z- 2z^2)$$

After rearranging and moving the $A(z)$ terms to the other side, I get:

$$A(z) = \frac{29-67z+23z^2+14z^3-24z^4}{(2z-1)^2(4z+1)(1-2z)(1-z)^2} $$

which turns into an absolutely hideous partial fraction decomposition, trying to solve for 6 constants. I pretty much went as far as I could go with it and still ran into a dead end, so i decided to try the usual method.

Doing the usual method, I try to solve the homogeneous part first, which is reasonably easy. My characteristic polynomial is $x^3-12x+16=0$, giving me roots $\lambda = 2 $(of multiplicity 2) and $\lambda = -4 $

So my solution to the homogeneous part is:

$$b_n = C_12^n+C_2n2^n+C_3(-4)^n$$

Now to get a particular solution, I try: $p_n = C_4n^2\cdot 6 \cdot 2^n + C_5n$

$$ \implies C_4n^2\cdot 6 \cdot 2^n + C_5n = 12(C_4(n-2)^2\cdot 6 \cdot 2^{(n-2)} + C_5(n-2)) - 16(C_4(n-3)^2\cdot 6 \cdot 2^{(n-3)} + C_5(n-3)) + 6\cdot2^n+25n $$

Another pretty nasty algebraic exercise (although not quite as bad as the generating function). However, I persist and after expanding the terms, I try to collect the $n^2\cdot2^n$ and $n$ terms together - to try and solve a simultaneous equation, but I run into the problem that I get terms without $n^2\cdot2^n$ nor $n$ and then some terms with $n\cdot 2^{n}$.

Would greatly appreciate some help with this practice question! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right about it being pretty nasty. The generating function is useful to get asymptotics (you only need to look at the singularities), but actually carrying out the partial fraction decomposition seems to require more persistence than is justifiable. :-)

Comment: By the way, $\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty} 6 \cdot 2^nz^n = (6)(2^3)\sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2^nz^n$, so your $\frac{6}{1-2z}$ term should actually be $\frac{48}{1-2z}$, right?

Comment: All but a couple of the partial fraction constants can be computed directly (without solving a system of linear equations), just by multiplying the rational function and the partial fraction template by $4z+1$ or $(1-z)^2$ (for example) and then plugging in $z=-1/4$ or $z=1$. That leaves a much simpler linear algebra problem. - By the way, do you mean for the denominator to include both $(2z-1)^2$ and $1-2z$?

Comment: Another relatively straightforward approach (though you still have to match initial conditions) would be to solve the _two_ inhomogeneous equations $g_n = 12g_{n-2}-16g_{n-3}+6\cdot 2^n$ and $g_n = 12g_{n-2}-16g_{n-3}+25n$; if $j_n$ is a solution of the first inhomogeneous equation and $k_n$ is a solution of the second, then (convince yourself of this!) $j_n+k_n$ is a solution of the full inhomogeneous equation.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I think you are right actually - but then wouldn't I have $\frac{1}{(1-2z)} - (1 + 2z+2^2z^2)$? How did you just pull $2^3$ out?

Comment: @GregMartin - Thanks for the advice - I'll give that a go. And yes, quite right, I should probably just combine them into $(1-2z)^3$.

Comment: @JackReacher: Actually the right expression is $48z^3/(1-2z)$: need to pull out both $2^3$ and $z^3$, to make the sum run from $0$ instead of $3$. Or you can do it as $6/(1-2z) - 6(1 + 2z + 2^2z^2)$ and get the same thing.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - yep, got it. I think we're on the same page.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - That is pretty interesting, I'm reading through my textbook, and doesn't say anything about this for non-homogeneous recurrence relations, but I can see that if I have $d_{n}$ satisfying the first said equation and $e_{n}$ satisfying the second, then adding them together and factoring out the constants for the first two terms in each, seems like it should give me a valid solution? Would it be correct to say that the two separate solutions should match the same initial conditions?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - or actually, would I have to account for the missing term in each, and adjust the initial conditions of both separate non-homogeneous relations? i.e. If I work with $g_{n} = 12a_{n-2}-16a_{n-3}+6\cdot2^n$ Then should my initial conditions be $g _{0} = 23, g _{1} = 37-25, g _{2} = 42-50$? (taking away the $25n$ term?

Comment: @JackReacher You'd have to find the _general_ solution for both - each of which will have three undetermined values - then add them together (where the indeterminates should collapse into three total indeterminates) and solve the 3x3 matrix to match conditions.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - ah ok, got you. Yeah I tried my first approach and it didn't work.

Comment: @GregMartin - Used your suggestions to knock out 3 of the constants, which made the rest of the computation somewhat easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I started your problem from scratch and arrived to something different (I have not been able to find where there has been a difference). First, I arrived to $$A(z)=\frac{-616 z^5+1540 z^4-1198 z^3+267 z^2+55 z-23}{(z-1)^2 (2 z-1)^3 (4 z+1)}$$ which decomposes as $$A(z)=-\frac{19}{z-1}-\frac{2}{(1-2 z)^2}+\frac{5}{(z-1)^2}-\frac{2}{(2 z-1)^3}-\frac{1}{4
   z+1}$$ Reworking from here, I arrived to quite messy expressions for $g_n$ which, fortunately, simplify to $$g_n=2^n (n+1) n+5 n-(-4)^n+24$$

Comment: I independently got the same $A(z)$ as you. (Well, I plugged in $\dfrac{23 + 12z - 284z^2 + 48z^3/(1-2z) + 25z/(1-z)^2}{1 - 12z^2 + 16z^3}$ into Wolfram Alpha: apart from the first expression above, it also gives the partial fraction decomposition thankfully.) The OP mistakenly wrote the $48z^3/(1-2z)$ term as $6/(1-2z)$, so that's the reason for the difference.

Comment: Thank you for confirming ! Cheers.

Comment: Also confirmed that the messy expression for $g_n$ given by the above, namely $19 - 2(n+1)2^n + 5(n+1) + 2\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}2^n - (-4)^n$ does indeed simplify to $-(-4)^n + 2^n(n+1)n + 5n + 24$ as you got. :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Thanks for your answer, I'll continue working through mine to see if I come up with the same thing. But kind of a dumb question here: since $(1-2z)^3$ has multiplicity $3$, wouldn't you need an extra term for $\frac{C}{(1-2z)}$ in your partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, $C$ happens to equal $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial $\lambda^3-12\lambda +16$ of the corresponding homogeneous difference equation
$$h_n-12 h_{n-2}+16 h_{n-3}=0\tag{1}$$
has $2$, $2$, $-4$ as  roots. The general solution of $(1)$ is therefore given by
$$h_n=(A+Bn) 2^n+ C(-4)^n$$
with arbitrary $A$, $B$, $C$.

On the right hand side of the given difference equation
$$g_n-12 g_{n-2}+16 g_{n-3}=6\cdot 2^n+25n\tag{2}$$
we see a linear combination of a solution of $(1)$ belonging to the eigenvalue $2$ of multiplicity $2$,  and a polynomial of degree $1$. For a particular solution $n\to p_n$ of $(2)$ we therefore make the "Ansatz"
$$p_n:= D\, n^2\>2^n + (E + F n)$$
and now have to determine $D$, $E$, $F$ such that $(2)$ is satisfied identically in $n$. Solving the resulting system of linear equations gives
$$p_n= n^2\>2^n+24+5 n\ .$$
The general solution of $(2)$ is therefore given by
$$g_n=h_n+p_n=\left(A+Bn+ n^2\right)2^n + C(-4)^n+24+5n\qquad(n\in{\mathbb Z})\ .$$
Finally the constants $A$, $B$, $C$ have to be determined by the initial condtions. One obtains $A=0$, $B=1$, $C=-1$, so that we have the following end result:
$$g_n=(n+n^2)\>2^n-(-4)^n+24+5n\ .$$

Comment: Thanks, I see where I was going wrong with my approach now. Not trying the correct form for $p_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I know: Define the generating function:
$$
G(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} g_n z^n
$$
Write the recurrence without subtraction in indices:
$$
g_{n + 3}
  = 12 g_{n + 1} - 16 g_n + 48 \cdot 2^n + 25 n + 75
$$
If you multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize the resulting sums:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} g_{n + k} z^k
  &= \frac{G(z) - g_0 - g_1 z - \ldots - z_{k - 1} z^{k - 1}}{z^k} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n
  &= \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n
  &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
  &= \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align}
to get:
$$
\frac{G(z) - 23 - 37 z - 42 z^2}{z^3}
  = 12 \frac{G(z) - 23}{z} - 16 G(z)
     + 48 \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
     + 25 \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2}
     + 75 \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
This gives the formidable:
\begin{align}
G(z)
  &= \frac{23 - 55 z - 267 z^2 + 1198 z^3 - 1540 z^4 + 612 z^5}
          {1 - 4 z + 7 z^2 - 62 z^3 + 124 z^4 - 104 z^5 + 32 z^6} \\
  &= \frac{19}{1 - z}
       + \frac{5}{(1 - z)^2}
       - \frac{2}{(1 - 2 z)^2}
       + \frac{2}{(1 - 2 z)^3}
       - \frac{1}{1 + 4 z}
\end{align}
Using the generalized binomial theorem,
in particular for natural $m$:
$$
(1 - u)^{-m}
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{m + k - 1}{m - 1} u^k
$$
and the expansion as polynomials of the binomial coefficients:
\begin{align}
g_n
  &= 19 
      + 5 \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1}
      - 2 \binom{n + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} \cdot 2^n
      + 2 \binom{n + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} \cdot 2^n
      - 4^n \\
  &= 24 + 5 n + (n^2 + n) \cdot 2^n - 4^n
\end{align}

The algebra help by [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) is gratefully aknowledged.

Comment: thanks. When you go from your 'formidable' G(z) to the partial fraction decomposition - would it be fair to say that there is no short cut here, but to simply hash out the algebra? I managed to do it, but just wondering if there was a shorter way.

Comment: @JackReacher, I don't see a simple way around it. Sorry.

Comment: no problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a homogeneous linear recurrence $A_n = c_1A_{n-1} + ... + c_kA_{n-k}$ call let $P_A(x)= x^k - c_1x^{k-1} -... -c_k$ be it's characteristic polynomial. The main theorem about these is that for any choice of initial values for $A_0, A_1, ... ,A_k$ we can write a unique closed form for $A_n$ as a linear combination of terms of the form $n^l\lambda^n$ where $\lambda$ is a root of$P_A(x)$ of multiplicity greater than $l$. Moreover any sequence of that form will satisfy the same recursion.

Now suppose we have a non-homogeneous recurrence of the form $A'_n = c_1A'_{n-1} + ... + c_kA'_{n-k} + B_n$, where $B_n$ satisfies a homogeneous linear recurrence with characteristic polynomial $P_B(x)$. The main result here is that $A'_n$ also satisfies a homogeneous recurrence relation, and in fact it satisfies the recurrence relation with characteristic polynomial $P_{A'}(x)=P_A(x)P_B(x)$.

So in light of these two results I can look at your question and know right away that it must have a closed form of the form $A_n= a_1 + a_2n + a_32^n + a_4n2^n + a_5n^22^n+a_6(-4)^n$ and from there solving for the coefficients is easy given the first few terms.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of these results? Especially the one about a sequence satisfying a nonhomogeneous recurrence also satisfying a homogeneous one.

Comment: Keep in mind I wrote this answer like three years ago, so I may have had a different source in mind at the time, but it's probably all in Stanley's enumerative combinatorics.  I think it's an easy calculation to verify that the recursion corresponding to the product of polynomials works though.